# Combine before splitting elements

Tags: r

I have a character vector. I want to combine adjacent rows where value is not a separator `\n`.
In the vector below, these are two elements.

```
 "Amount of pensions received mens.",   "(Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"
```

It should be combined as `"Amount of pensions received mens. (Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"`

```
mat <- c("Dolphin Sentimental S.r.l.", "\n", "Tiger Sentiyapa S.r.l.", 
      "\n", "Effort rate calculates to grant (Debt to Income Rate)", 
      "\n", "Amount of pensions received mens.", "(Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))", 
      "\n", "Effort rate calculates to grant (Debt to Income Rate)", 
      "\n", "Amount of pensions received mens.", "(Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"
    )
```

**Desired Output**

```
[1] "Dolphin Sentimental S.r.l."                                                       
[2] "Tiger Sentiyapa S.r.l."                                                           
[3] "Effort rate calculates to grant (Debt to Income Rate)"                            
[4] "Amount of pensions received mens. (Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"
[5] "Effort rate calculates to grant (Debt to Income Rate)"                            
[6] "Amount of pensions received mens. (Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#paste together (collapse to 1 long string), then split using '\n' as separator
strsplit(paste0(mat, collapse = ""), "\\n")

# [[1]]
# [1] "Dolphin Sentimental S.r.l."                                                      
# [2] "Tiger Sentiyapa S.r.l."                                                          
# [3] "Effort rate calculates to grant (Debt to Income Rate)"                           
# [4] "Amount of pensions received mens.(Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"
# [5] "Effort rate calculates to grant (Debt to Income Rate)"                           
# [6] "Amount of pensions received mens.(Grant data) (Pension Received (Monthly Basis))"
```